# Syntax for "is distributed as" in R

Tags: r, distribution, jags

When specifying a model in JAGS/BUGS, the "is distributed as" symbol `~` is very useful. How to do this in R when using MCMC methods which require me to specify the likelihood?

Let's say, I want to estimate three parameters which are multivariate normally distributed. 
In JAGS, I would do this by specifying `pars[1:n] ~ dmnorm(mu[1:3], sigma[1:3, 1:3])`. If everything is specified correctly, JAGS would go on to estimate these parameters under the given distribution.

In R, there are similar functions, like the `dmvnorm()` function, from the mvtnorm package. However, I'm not sure how to use these. I have to provide the data to get the probability density, whereas in JAGS, I only have to provide the parameters of the distribution like mu and sigma. What is the R equivalent to the `~` syntax in JAGS?

Comment: Your question is not highly clear. Did you already attempt to code this MCMC in R ? If so, can you provide the code ? Or do you have a link to the algorithm ? In JAGS we define a model and JAGS runs a Gibbs sampler to estimate the parameters. Maybe you're looking for `rmvnorm` (function to sample from the multivariate normal), and not `dmvnorm` (function which evaluates the density). But I'm not sure about what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some random data:

```
set.seed(123)
y = rbinom(10, 1, 0.2)
y
```

```
> y
 [1] 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

So we **know** that the value of p that generated this data is 0.2. Let's see how we could try and recover that information (assuming we didn't know it). In JAGS I would write the following model:

```
model{
  for(i in 1:10){
    y[i] ~ dbern(p)
  }
  p ~ dunif(0, 1)
}
```

So I have said that the data is generated using (or sampled from) a Bernoulli distribution with parameter `p`, and that the prior for `p` is a Beta(1,1) which is equivalent to a uniform distribution.

So let's (initially) forget the Bayesian part. You have asked how to compute the likelihood. The likelihood for a parameter theta given independent and identically distributed data y = (y_1, ..., y_N) is

L(theta | y) = product(f(y_i | theta), i = 1,...,N)

In our example, the pdf f(y_i | theta) is p^y_i * (1 - p)^(1 - y_i). I know this just simplifies to p if y_i is 1, or (1 - p) if y_i is zero, but let's assume we don't know this and we are just using the Binomial probability function with parameters n = 1, and p to compute this, then you could get the likelihood like this:

```
Like = function(p){
  prod(dbinom(y, 1, p))
}
```

This is a pretty simple function that only works for single values of `p`, but it works, e.g.

```
> Like(0.1)
[1] 0.0004782969
> Like(0.2)
[1] 0.001677722
> Like(0.3)
[1] 0.002223566
>
```

We can make it work for a whole range of values of `p` by using `sapply`

```
Like = function(p){
  sapply(p, function(p.i)prod(dbinom(y, 1, p.i)))
}
```

So now, for example I could calculate the likelihood of values of `p` ranging from 0.01 to  0.99 in steps of 0.01 by

```
p = seq(0.01, 0.99, by = 0.01)
l = Like(p)
```

And I could plot them

```
plot(p, l, type = "l")
```

[image]

You can see from the plot that the likelihood is maximized at 0.3, so this is the MLE of `p` based on this data.

Going back to the Bayesian problem, here's an implementation of Metropolis-Hastings (uncommented sorry):

```
MH = function(N = 1000, p0 = runif(1)){
  log.like = function(p){
    sum(dbinom(y, size = 1, p, log = TRUE))
  }

  ll0 = log.like(p0)
  r = c(p0, rep(0, N))

  for(i in 1:N){
    p1 = runif(1)
    ll1 = log.like(p1)

    if(ll1 > ll0 || log(runif(1)) < ll1 - ll0){
      p0 = p1
      ll0 = ll1
    }

    r[i + 1] = p0
  }

  return(r)
}
```

Now we take a sample of size 10,000 from this, with

```
set.seed(123)
p = MH(10000)  
plot(density(p))    
abline(v = c(mean(p), mean(p) + c(-1,1)*qnorm(0.975)*sd(p)))
```

and plot the KDE of the sample (plus some credible intervals)

[image]

And see that the Metropolis-Hastings has worked -- the intervals are wide because the sample size is small.